# Inserting a while loop inside a for. Consider this a brain teaser

Tags: c#, c++, c

I heard recently from some of my friends that he managed to insert a while loop inside a for. And I by "inside" I mean literally inside. I tried it in C/C++. Something like this:

```
for( exp1; while(); exp2)
{
exp3;
}
```

or

```
for(exp1; exp2; while())
{
exp3;
}
```

I've tried both ways but I don't seem to manage to make it work. Did anyone else tried this? Can someone show me an example that works?

Comment: I think you're friend was lying or maybe you simply misheard him/her.

Comment: `he managed to insert a while loop inside a for` Why not ask himself how?

Comment: I cannot cite exact fragment of the standard but I think that foe expects expressions, and control structures (like `while`) will not work. But most importantly, I would ask - what would you need it for?

Comment: dont see why quite so many downvotes, it's a perfectly reasonable question.

Comment: @danp: I didn't downvote, but I imagine they are for the fact that this question is essentially "I heard an anecdote about this impractical thing. How do I do it?". Plus the language tag spam.

Comment: ok, but just frowning at hammering a new user with downvotes without saying why.

Answer (score 3):

The two programs are not valid in C.

`for` loops clauses in C have to be expressions (or a declaration for the first clause). A statement, for example a `while` statement, is not allowed.

Answer (score 3):

```
for( int a = 17; 1 != [&](){while(!(a%2)){a/=2;};return a;}(); a=a*3+1){
  std::cout <<a<<"\n";
}
```

is a `while` inside a `for`.

Comment: Is this a C++11 implementation of Collatz?

Comment: @iwillnotexistidonotexist Yes.  It only prints out odd steps however.  I was looking for a non trivial way to use the `while`, and naturally wanted to answer the question two people said could not be done.

Comment: I've never seen C++11 lambda expressions in the wild before, this is a good example. +1. But I have a sneaking suspicion that OP saw a GCC statement expression with a `while` in it. A statement expression in a `for` would resemble `for(a = 17; ({while((a%2) & 1 == 0){a/=2;} a;}) != 1 ; a=3*a+1);`. Note the characteristic `({ /*expr*/ })` syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The for statement in its general form (excluding the range-based for) in fact consists from three expressions:init expression, condition expression, and one more expression. The statement while is not an expression statement so it may not be used in expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that you cannot insert a `while` statement like this into `for` loops in C. From what I've learned the syntax for the `for` loop is like this:

```
for(initializer; condition; increment) 
...
```

From the textbook, it says it can only take in clauses and expressions.

The `while` statement creates a structured loop that executes as long as the condition specified within `while` is true at the start of each iteration. So, I think the `while` condition is for the `while` statement itself, and not for the `for` loop. Cheers.